# Error in $A.getCallback() [Cannot read property 'setParam' of null] Callback failed: apex://InsertContact_Account/ACTION$saveAcc

Tags: lightning-aura-components

### Iam getting this Error when I tried to set the parameter in Event.

This page has an error. You might just need to refresh it.

```
Error in $A.getCallback() [Cannot read property 'setParam' of null]
Callback failed: apex://InsertContact_Account/ACTION$saveAcc
Failing descriptor: {markup://c:AccInsertComp}
```

---

My event File Name is :- `Account_Event.evt`

```
<aura:event type="COMPONENT" description="Event template" >
<aura:attribute name="accId" type="string" />
</aura:event>
```

---

My Child component Name is:- `AccInsertComp.cmp`

```
<aura:component controller="InsertContact_Account">   
    <aura:attribute name="Acc" type="Account" default="{'sObjectType':'Account'}"/>
    <aura:attribute name="EventString" type="string"/>
    <aura:registerEvent name="AccEvent" type="c:Account_Event"/>
    <lightning:card title="New Account">
        <aura:set attribute="actions">
            <lightning:button label="Insert" variant="success"  onclick="{!c.insertAccount}"/>
        </aura:set >
        <lightning:input label="AccountName:" value="{!v.Acc.name}"/>
         <lightning:input label="Phone:" value="{!v.Acc.phone}"/>
        <lightning:input label="Industry:" value="{!v.Acc.Industry}"/>
        <lightning:input label="Rating:" value="{!v.Acc.Rating}"/>        
    </lightning:card>
</aura:component>
```

---

My Js Controller is:-

```
({
    insertAccount : function(component, event, helper) {
        var accR=component.get("v.Acc");
        console.log("The value of object" +accR.name,+accR.phone,+accR.Rating,+accR.Industry);
        var action=component.get("c.saveAcc");
        console.log("Action called");
        action.setParams({accRecord:JSON.stringify(accR)});
        console.log("object string"+JSON.stringify(accR));
       action.setCallback(this,function(res){
           var state=res.getState();
           if(state=='SUCCESS'){
               var accountId=res.getReturnValue();
              // component.set("v.EventString",accountId);
               console.log("The value of Id"+accountId);
               var eventRef = component.getEvent("accEvent");
               alert('I am after event get');
               eventRef.setParam("accId",accountId);------> Getting error here
               alert('Iam after set');
               eventRef.fire();              
           } 
           else{
               console.log("Response Failed");
           }
       });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    }
})
```

Comment: Please use the `{}` tool in the editor to format your code.. Right now, no one can read it.

Comment: My Event is    <aura:event type="COMPONENT" description="Event template" >
<aura:attribute name="accId" type="string" />
</aura:event>

Comment: Please do not post comments. **[Edit] your post.**

Comment: From apex your return type is Id or string? If it is Id , can you try updating type of the event attribute to Id from string.

Answer (score 2):

Your issue is in the ***case*** of the variable name.

You have registered the event with name as `AccEvent`

```
<aura:registerEvent name="AccEvent" type="c:Account_Event"/>
```

And trying to use `accEvent` which is not same as declared

```
var eventRef = component.getEvent("accEvent"); // name mismatch
```

Change to below and it should work

```
var eventRef = component.getEvent("AccEvent"); // name should be same as declared
```

---

From the [docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_cb_init_handler.htm) (emphasis mine):

> To get a reference to a component event in JavaScript, use `cmp.getEvent("evtName")` where `evtName` **matches the name attribute** in `<aura:registerEvent>`.